# loop not terminating

Tags: haskell

The function below wants to either receive and ack or wait until its duetime has come and return.

Now, it works when it receives and ack. It works correctly when no ack is received and waits until duetime.

When the duetime is reached it freezes. It seems that it is not exiting my self constructed loop correctly. I have also tried with if-then-else, but same result. I do not want to use whileM.

How do I correctly exit the loop?

```
import Network.Socket hiding (send, sendTo, recv, recvFrom)
import Network.Socket.ByteString


waitAck s duetime' = do
      print ("in")
      (a, _) <- recvFrom s 4711
      now' <- getPOSIXTime
      unless (B.unpack a == "ack") (when (now' < duetime') (waitAck s duetime'))
      print (B.unpack a)
      return ()
```

Comment: So, the only time you check `duetime'` is after you've already recieved some data - you've got no instruction to stop waiting for input after a timeout passes.  You need to find the haskell equivalent to [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

Comment: 'recvFrom' is IMHO not blocking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct solution is to race two threads, one that waits for the ack, and one that waits for the time. Kill the one that loses the race. Perhaps this (untested) code will give you a hint about how:

```
import Control.Concurrency.MVar

withTimeout :: Int -> IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
withTimeout n io = do
    mvar    <- newEmptyMVar
    timeout <- forkIO (threadDelay n >> putMVar mvar Nothing)
    action  <- forkIO (io >>= putMVar mvar . Just)
    result  <- takeMVar mvar
    killThread timeout
    killThread action
    return result

waitAck s timeout = withTimeout timeout go where
    go = do
        (a, _) <- recvFrom s 4711
        if B.unpack a == "ack" then print (B.unpack a) else go
```

edit: It seems that `base` provides [System.Timeout.timeout](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Timeout.html#v%3atimeout) for exactly this purpose. Its implementation is more likely to be correct than this one, too.

Comment: thanks for the timeout thing. Will look into this. Conc the MVar is expect this to be quite slow if it is used at larger scale. I try to craft something very fast that gets along with minimal amount of code.I will try the MVar things as well.

Comment: Any idea why `Just a <- timeout 50 (recvFrom s 4711)` would return a pattern match error at runtime when timeout is reached

Comment: @JFritsch: Because if it times out, the result is `Nothing` which of course doesn't match `Just a`.

Comment: @hammar Have tried `fromMaybe 0 $ timeout ... ` etc. also that gives an error Maybe a0 ... with actual type IO (Maybe a1). Would this require liftIO or liftM somehow?

Comment: @JFritsch Yes, you would need `liftM (fromMaybe 0) (timeout ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an iterative loop. You don't place any conditions on the stuff after the recursive call, so when the conditions finally fail, the whole thing will unwind, printing once for every recursive call. I suspect that might be enough to make it appear frozen.

Try something like this:

```
waitAck s duetime' = do
    print ("in")
    (a, _) <- recvFrom s 4711
    now' <- getPOSIXTime
    if B.unpack a == "ack" || now' >= duetime'
        then print (B.unpack a)
        else waitAck s duetime'
```

Comment: freezes when duetime is reached. exactly the same result. I had never expected that this compiles since I would have expected that cond1 || cond2 must be both of the same type.

Comment: @JFritsch: In that case it sounds like `recvFrom` is blocking. Also, `B.unpack a == "ack"` and `now' >= duetime'` both have type `Bool`.